# Access Rails app from Fedora (guest virtual machine) in Windows XP (host)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vmware, fedora, ethernet, nat

I have installed *Fedora 14* on *Windows XP* using *VMware* with **NAT** as ethernet type (since I need to access internet through wireless data card). I am using Fedora for **Rails** app development, which i can access using normal Webrick on http://localhost:3000

Any ideas on how to access the same app in the **host Windows XP** machine with Rails app server running on Fedora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to connect via the IP-Address + port of the Fedora box? To find out the IP-Address use `ifconfig` and type it in your Windows-Browser, i.e. http://192.168.1.100:3030

If this fails, did you check your firewall settings on the Fedora box?

Comment: it works perfecly...i had to disable firewall completly in fedora box, Any sugesstions on adding an exception to the firewall rules without disabling them alltogether

Comment: I don't know which firewall Fedora is using, but I wouldn't bother because its a VM. Attacks on this machine are very unlikely or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'bridged' or 'host-only' network types to get an IP address accessible to the host machine.